# Empty output files using MapReduce MultipleOutputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using MultipleOutputs in my Reducer as I want to have separate result file for each key, however, each of the result file is empty though default result file part-r-xxxx is created and contains correct values.

This is my code for JobDriver and Reducer

Main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int currentIteration = 0;
    int reducerCount, roundCount;

    Configuration conf = createConfiguration(currentIteration);
    cleanEnvironment(conf);
    Job job = new Job(conf, "cfim");

    //Input and output format configuration
    job.setMapperClass(TransactionsMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(PatriciaReducer.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TransactionInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    reducerCount = roundCount = Math.floorDiv(getRoundCount(conf), Integer.parseInt(conf.get(MRConstants.mergeFactorSpecifier)));

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/cloudera/datasets/input"));
    Path outputPath = new Path(String.format(MRConstants.outputPathFormat, outputDir, currentIteration));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "key", TextOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Reducer class

```
public class PatriciaReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

private ITreeManager treeManager;
private SerializationManager serializationManager;
private MultipleOutputs<LongWritable, Text> mos;

@Override 
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException ,InterruptedException {
    treeManager = new PatriciaTreeManager();
    serializationManager = new SerializationManager();
    mos = new MultipleOutputs<LongWritable, Text>(context);
}

@Override
protected void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> items, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Iterator<Text> patriciaIterator = items.iterator();
    PatriciaTree tree = new PatriciaTree();

    if (patriciaIterator.hasNext()){
        Text input = patriciaIterator.next();
        tree = serializationManager.deserializePatriciaTree(input.toString());
    }

    while(patriciaIterator.hasNext()){
        Text input = patriciaIterator.next();
        PatriciaTree mergeableTree = serializationManager.deserializePatriciaTree(input.toString());
        tree = treeManager.mergeTree(tree, mergeableTree, false);
    }

    Text outputValue = new Text(serializationManager.serializeAsJson(tree));
    mos.write("key", key, outputValue, generateOutputPath(key));
    context.write(key, outputValue);
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.finalize();
    mos.close();
}

private String generateOutputPath(LongWritable key) throws IOException {
    String outputPath = String.format("%s-%s", MRConstants.reduceResultValue, key.toString());
    return outputPath;
}
```

}

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This question seems a bit off-topic. What have you tried so far to nail down the problem? Debugging or testing specific scenarios?

Comment: Well, I noticed that the result files are created, however they are empty, though result is not, however, since I am using built-in output format, I just tried looking for similar issues in web

Comment: Seems as you already found the solution yourself. Don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted solution. Or consider removing your question if it is so specific that others would not benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I was using wrong method to close multiple outputs object. After closing MultipleOutputs in cleanup method rather than finalize method everything is working perfect